# How to determine the value of $f(x)$ if we know $f'(x)$? (Concrete example in the text)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let

$f(x) = 21/x$

$f'(x) = -21/x^2$

So $f(4) = 5.25$ and $f'(4)= -\frac{21}{16}$

Is there a way, and if yes, how to calculate $f(3)$ if we only know $f(4)$ and $f'(x)$ without calculating with the original $f(x)$ function ?

Comment: Are you referring to that particular function or are you looking for a general case?

Comment: Why are you asking that ?

Comment: Is $f$ defined in an interval (conncted set )?

Comment: Your question is a little contradictory. You want to compute $f(3)$ without computing $f(x)$. So what do you precisely mean by "without calculating with the original function" ??

Comment: @Tilsight Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

We can integrate $f'(x)$ to find $f(x)$ up to a constant and we use $f(4)$ to find the constant.

For example if $f'(x) = x^3+1$, then $f(x)= x^4/4+x+c$

If  we know that  $f(4) = 65$, we have     $f(4)= 4^4/4+4+c=65$ which implies, $c=-3$ and $f(x)=x^4/4+x-3$

Now you can find $f(3)=81/4$

Answer (score 0):

If we know $f'(x)$ and $f(4)$ we have that

$$f(x)=f(4)+\int_4^x f'(t) dt$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have is called a differential equation, i.e. you have an equation that involves a function and its derivative.

Technically, the solution is obtained using an integral,

$$f(3)=f(4)+\int_4^3 f'(x)\,dx$$

but this is essentially a way to retrieve the function $f(x)$ so I would tend to answer *no* to your question.

---

Anyway, there are so-called numerical methods that allow you to estimate the integral without building an analytical expression for the function and can return an approximation of $f(3)$ as the output of an algorithm.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: I am not. Fixed.